# How to remove a parameter from query string and rewrite URL?

Tags: windows, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a URL that appears like this

```
http://www.domain.com/previous-winners/?ceremony=406&title=2015
```

and i'm trying to rewrite this with my .htaccess file to appear like this. Keeping the title parameter and dropping the ceremony one.

```
http://www.domain.com/previous-winners/2015
```

This is what i have so far

```
RewriteRule ^previous-winners/$2  /previous-winners/?ceremony=$1&title=$2  [NC]
```

But i'm not really sure where to go next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this rule in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^previous-winners/([^/]*)$ /previous-winners/?ceremony=406&title=$1 [L]
```

It will leave you with the URL: `http://www.domain.com/previous-winners/2015`

Just make sure you clear your cache before you test this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does it matter that the ceremony value will change, but you've hard coded it in the example?

Comment: Since the ceremony is hidden it shouldn't affect it. However, you can code it as `ceremony=$1` if you prefer.